# Use tap or touch instead mouse javascript changes

Tags: javascript

I have this script,

```
$('.dot').click(function(){
     var modal = $(this).attr('id');
      $('.mask').has('article.' + modal).fadeIn(300);
      $('.mask article.' + modal).fadeIn(0).animate({
    'top' : '10%'
  }, 300);
    });
 }
```

It works fine with the mouse. But i want to use tab or touch on the ‘dot’.

What do i have to change?

SOLVED
Did change it to    $('.dot').on(‘click touchstart’, function(){

Comment: do you want to modify elements when `.dot`  is "activated" or "focused", is it? If yes, why don't you use `$(".dot").on("focus", ...)`

Comment: I did try .on(‘click touchstart’, function(){ after searching a lot sources. This works. I Will try Your suggestion later on.